# How to provide console Input from Java Web application

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, console

Hi I am using java spring MVC  framework in my application. I am facing problem to handle  the java console from web application .In below I am providing sample code:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/consoleInput",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String takingInput(Model model ){
    logger.info("/ConsoleInput mapping is begin");
    System.out.println("Enter any things:");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s=sc.next();
    System.out.println("Yours input is :"+s);
    model.addAttribute("input", s);

    logger.info("/ConsoleInput mapping is end");

    return"console";
}
```

So my problem is how can I give control to end user to provide the needed input when he is on web page and don’t have any idea about what is happening on back end.
The above code is something is an example .so In web application console needed a input from user then how we can provide this input from webpage or how we can know on web page , this application needed input by user to continue rest of part.

If I am not able to explain this problem properly  or something still I am missing please let me know.

I am using tomcat 7, java 7 and spring MVC framework

Your help would be appreciated.

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Do you want user to type something in the webpage and the server will respond according to it? Something like a chat application?

Comment: Why you are not getting input from a input text field of html and further get it from http request paramater ?

Comment: Of course I want to give input to the server ,but what is happening in the console level it is asking to provide some input based on this input application will be continue but my struggling point is how user will know some input is need from my side and how he will provide to this input form web page ( I mean to say how to interact with console)

Comment: The texfield input is not require because my java application is interacting with met-lab function and this needed input is coming by this function . So In a core program it very easy to handle but I am not getting any idea how I can do it with web apps